# WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 version is compatible with WSO2 IS 5.6.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 version and trying to integrate with WSO2 Identity Server v 5.6.0

Identity Server 5.6.0 is already present in the project so we donot want to make any changes in that.
However, due to technical road block in APIM 2.5.0, I am trying to migrate APIM from 2.5.0 to 2.6.0.

APIM is migrated as it is provided in the documentation link but when I am trying to integrate with IS 5.6.0, its not happening as it should be. The token which are generated from IS 5.6.0 are not authorize in APIM 2.6.0 and its throwing error as below

```
ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Invalid OAuth Token : Invalid Access 
Token. Access token is not ACTIVE.
[2019-09-09 08:49:07,825] ERROR - WebAppAuthenticatorImpl Authentication 
failed. Please check your username/password
```

There are no changes in the process as to how we used to generate the token earlier and perform operations when APIM 2.5.0 and Identity Server 5.6.0 was integrated.

Can some one please let me know if the compatibility exists between APIM 2.6.0 and Identity 5.6.0

Thanks

Comment: You may want to check configure the [IS as a Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager) (which is default bundle to download). As already answered, there is a compatibility matrix you should stick to

Answer (score 2):

Compatibility between APIM 2.6.0 and IS 5.6.0 can't be guaranteed as it's not officially tested by WSO2. The compatible IS version for APIM 2.6.0 is IS 5.7.0.